# SharePoint 2010 createFolder Dws not creating the folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to generate a folder in a library of SharePoint 2010, through a Java application that connects to the site via Web Service (Dws), but i get an ID=3 (NoAccess, wich means "The user does not have sufficient rights", according to the documentation) as return

My user has "Total Control" on the library. No problem if I create a folder using the web interface.

I made this test: created a folder through web interface and then I executed the createFolder through my app. In this case, I'm getting a message that says the folder already exists, wich means I get to the correct "site-library-folderTocreate".

I'm actually out of ideas right now, and I don't have much knowledge about SharePoint, so any help will be great!

Thanks in advance.

A.

Some additional data:

Site   : prueba

Library: Repositorio Desarrollo

Folder : docs

WSDL    : http://'localmachine'/prueba/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx?wsdl

Endpoint: http://'localmachine'/prueba/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx

Folder  : Repositorio Desarrollo/docs (already tried with "%20" instead of blank space)

Sorry, think I've should post this before: the code in simple version.

```
public void create() {
    try {
        DwsSoap dwsSoap = getDwsSoap();
        createFolder(dwsSoap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Nooooooooooo... : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private DwsSoap getDwsSoap() throws Exception {
    URL urlDws = new URL("http://'localmachine'/prueba/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx?wsdl");
    Dws dws = new Dws(urlDws, new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/", "Dws"));
    DwsSoap dwsSoap = dws.getDwsSoap();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) dwsSoap;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, getProperties().getProperty("username"));
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, getProperties().getProperty("password"));
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://'localmachine'/prueba/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx");
    return dwsSoap;
}

private boolean createFolder(DwsSoap p_port) {
    try {
        String result = p_port.createFolder("Repositorio Desarrollo/docs");
        logger.info(result);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Some error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already fixed: it was a permission issue!

It happens that the user needs permission not only over the library, but in the site too. So, they created a new site with the user having access to create the library and it worked.

Hope this is useful to somebody else.

Regards,
A.